# iOS & Facebook: upload an image along with user comment to the wall

Tags: ios, facebook, sharekit

I have an app, it takes screenshot of itself and I would like to post it on user's wall along with a comment.

The problem is, I seemingly tried every option and none of it works:

- `[facebook dialog:@"feed" ...]` doesn't work because you can supply only a URL, not a UIImage.
- `[facebook requestWithGraphPath ...]` doesn't work because the user is not prompted for the comment.
- I could first (silently) try to upload the screenshot with `requestWithGraphPath` and then feed its newly created URL to `dialog` which doesn't work because of "FBCDN image is not allowed in stream". All of this is of course using callbacks which, including login callback, makes for nice big mess.
- I even tried `ShareKit` but forgot about it after the app strangely could/couldn't login.

Please, how can I share both an image and a comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using facebook's latest iOS SDK, in Hackbook sample app, look for  APICallsViewController.m file.  There is this method that you can post using UIImage directly:

```
/*
 * Graph API: Upload a photo. By default, when using me/photos the photo is uploaded
 * to the application album which is automatically created if it does not exist.
 */
- (void) apiGraphUserPhotosPost {
    NSString *sourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
    NSString *file1 = [sourcePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/MP1101frame1002.jpg"];
    UIImage *img = [[[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:file1]autorelease];

    [self showActivityIndicator];
    currentAPICall = kAPIGraphUserPhotosPost;
    HackbookAppDelegate *delegate = (HackbookAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 

    // Download a sample photo
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.facebook.com/images/devsite/iphone_connect_btn.jpg"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
//    UIImage *img  = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];   //here you can insert your UIImage
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   yourMessageHere, @"message",  //whatever message goes here
                                   img, @"picture",   //img is your UIImage
                                   nil];
    [[delegate facebook] requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                          andParams:params
                      andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                        andDelegate:self];
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know how to upload an image, thanks. But to post a comment along with the image?

Comment: I just edited my answer to show how to include message as well.  It is:  yourMessageHere, @"message".  Where yourMessageHere is NSString.  "message" is key for the params dictionary.

Comment: "doesn't work because the user is not prompted for the comment" - if I want the user to write the comment how should I go about it? Do I have to implement the prompt myself in Cocoa or is there a way to make Facebook API help me?

Comment: You will need to DIY to prompt user to get message.  It is much better that way as well since you can choose however you want to present the prompt to user.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, you may want to try the latest development branch of ShareKit at this address:
https://github.com/Sharekit/Sharekit

It has significant improvements added by the community over the canonical version.